# Code for add or update Invoice in code wise using PHP v3 SDK for QBO

Tags: quickbooks

I am using "PHP v3 SDK for QBO". I edited customer_query.php in the _sample folder to get the customer & which is working fine. Like this   how can I  add & upadte the invoice against a customer in code wise. I did not find any example in the sample folder of PHP v3 SDK for QBO. Please help me how can i add or update an invoice (Using v3 SDK for QBO). Please give code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have examples for that specific SDK, but if you use the open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Then there are examples here of doing this:

- add - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php
- update - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_update.php
- query - https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_query.php

The code ends up looking something like this:

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

$Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

$Invoice->setDocNumber('WEB' . mt_rand(0, 10000));
$Invoice->setTxnDate('2013-10-11');

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(12.95 * 2);
$Line->setDescription('Test description goes here.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(12.95);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(2);

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line);

$Invoice->setCustomerRef('67');


if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realm, $Invoice))
{
    print('Our new Invoice ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($InvoiceService->lastError());
}
```